# In rails, what's the best way to deal with really large files (e.g. videos) that you do not want to commit to the repo and asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, asset-pipeline, assets, asset-sync

I've got a rails app.

And I've got some really large videos on it in the asset pipeline (couple of gigs worth).

What I want to do is remove these videos from the repo and deploy process, becuase huge and it slows the process.

However I still want them to act in a similar way to the asset pipeline and asset sync. And be versioned by changes to the repo.

What's the best way to handle large videos/files in a repo like this?

Comment: Using some kinds of cloud service like youtube and iframe it to your RoR app?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/), it allows handling of large files in git.